# After changing page in jquery mobile, google map loads just partly

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

I've got home page in jquery mobile that has link to another page where map is all over the screen with header on top. When I go to that link with the map, the map loads just partly (as you can see on screenshot) and when I try to move it, it jumps back.

[image: Map screenshot]

As you can see the canvas is properly loaded, because down there is google map logo and Terms of use. What is wrong with that?

One fact: When I refresh the map page (not starting on home page) or when I resize the browser window when I'm on map page, it shows up perfectly fine.

Comment: show us your page markup. It could be a div problem in `data-role=content`.

Comment: try this `$(document).bind('pageinit', '[data-role='page']#map', function()` instead of `$(document).bind('pageinit', function()`

Comment: Nope, still the same issue, but that's great piece of code, it won't load the map every time I change the page :)

Comment: Maybe I'm looking for an event that fires after the DOM is loaded, not before, which as far as I'm concerned, 'pageinit' does. But I can't find that event anywhere on google.

Comment: sorry, my bad, that's because it's initiated and loaded inside the DOM.

Comment: So, what's wrong with that?

Comment: I'm working on it, i'm thinking of the right event.

Comment: One more thing, when I add setTimeout(function() {initMap();},500); it loads fine. But I hate to use this workarounds that doesn't really work every time. Anyway, it has to be a timing issue.

Comment: got it, `$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '[data-role="page"]#map' , function()` as is. mind `'` and `"`.

Comment: NICE! Add it as an answer, works wonderful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map is loaded into DOM on `pageinit`, therefore it doesn't now obtain the right screen/window measures. Thus, you have to bind initializing the map to `pagebeforeshow` as it allow the map to get the screen size.

Here's how it works.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '[data-role="page"]#map' , function()
```

instead of

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function()
```

Comment: Hi Omar, my function is called `initializeMap()`. Where should I place the document call you suggested above? thanks

Comment: @Malloc hi, which JQM version are you using? Can you post a separate question with all details? :)

Comment: Hi. I am using jquery 1.11.0 and jquery mobile 1.4.2. Ok I am posting a separate question

Comment: Here is my question post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23176423/google-maps-is-not-loaded-after-page-transition

Answer (score 3):

Trigger a refresh on the map. This can happen when the map container changes size, or is hidden initially and then shown. Same thing happens, for instance, when using jQuery UI tabs and the map is initialized on on a hidden tab.

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')
```

Comment: That's a great stuff, too. Thanks, I was looking for this in connection with something else.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and finally solved it by triggering the 'resize' twice.  Like this:

```
$("#mapelement").height(10);
$("#mapelement").width(10);
google.maps.event.trigger(googlemap, 'resize');
setTimeout(function() {
    adjustMapSize();  // set the correct size of #mapelement
    google.maps.event.trigger(googlemap, 'resize');
    updateMap();     // center the map and display markers
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('pageshow', "#name-page", function() {
    initialize();
});
```

Try this,