# Embed google map is wrong displayed until resizing webpage

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I am trying to display a map in my webpage to get coordinates from it. It works fine, I can drag and drop a marker and get coordinates in input boxes.

But my problem comes when I load the webpage. Everything is well displayed but the map, here you can see how the map is displayed:

[image: Wrong map]

But if in this moment I resize the webpage, I mean, if it was full screen, put it half. Or make it a little big bigger or smaller if it was just a part of the screen. Then, You will see the correct map:
[image: right map]

(It is not the same place, I know. I took the image from 2 reloads)

I create the webpage in HTML but I call it as if they were distinct webpages. When you load the index, you get a button with this

```
href:<a href="#openMap">
```

And, the part showed will be:

```
<div data-role="page"  id="openMap" data-theme="e">
<div data-role="header" data-id="fixedNav" data-position="fixed">
    blablabla
    <div data-role="content">
        <form action="">
            <div id="map_canvas" style="width:500px; height:300px"></div>
            blablabla
```

And all divs, forms... properly closed. I have many input boxes and fields which I haven't put them here.

Then, in my google map script I have this:

```
var map;
function initializeNewMap() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.462119485,-3.809954692009);

  var myOptions = {
     zoom: 14,
     center: myLatlng,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions); 

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      draggable: true,
      position: myLatlng, 
      map: map,
      title: "Your location"
  });

}
```

But I have no idea why I need to resize. Is it a way to solve it?

EDIT: I add more info:

I call the part of the webpage which has the map this way:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", '#openMap', function() {
```

I tried to put

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

just after it but nothing happens.

### SOLUTION:

I found the solution in other question ([Google Maps v3 load partially on top left corner, resize event does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17059816/google-maps-v3-load-partially-on-top-left-corner-resize-event-does-not-work), Ian Devlin post):

As one user said here, I need to resize map. But just that line didn't work. I added this code at the end of the initialize function:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
});
```

So it is just called after the map is shown.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google maps api - map sometimes appears only on upper left corner of its div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803323/google-maps-api-map-sometimes-appears-only-on-upper-left-corner-of-its-div)

Comment: I think the answer is the resize trigger but it doesn't work. I added info about the initializing way of that part of the webpage. Because I don't know where to put the trigger line.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470980/unable-to-get-google-maps-api-v3-to-completely-load-on-jquery-mobile

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15391478/after-changing-page-in-jquery-mobile-google-map-loads-just-partly

Comment: This is the right way to do it but if this only happens on the initial draw, shouldn't you run clearListeners just before triggering the resize event? Otherwise, every idle event triggers an unnecessary resize.

Comment: This should never happen unless something is setup wrong, I can almost bet the DOM is not ready and the map-canvas object does not have a proper dimension set.. I've never ever had to use resize.. Make sure you load google maps in the correct fashion and this will not occur... This is a bug due to being loaded way to early.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I too faced this issue, I solved it by triggering the Google maps **`resize`** event.

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

**Updates:**

```
var map;
function initializeNewMap() {
 // add your code
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions); 
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
}
```

Hope you understand.

Comment: Where do you call this event?

Comment: I tried to put it outside initialize function but after it and nothing happends

Comment: @Biribu add this code at the end of the `initializeNewMap`function

Comment: As shown in the question, idle is a better event than resize.

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue but you couldn't see any of the map (the entire box was grey).

What solved it for me was realising that the div that contained the map was starting off as hidden using

```
display:none;
```

If you instead use

```
visibility:hidden;
```

The div retains its size while still appears as hidden, so the map when initialised uses its correct height and width, rather than 0 values

Hope this helps!

Comment: I thought I would add to say that I had to add the map initialisation to a callback on the big reveal of the page contents otherwise the fadein animation didn't finished before I tried to reveal the map and it still wouldn't work.

      $('#Results').fadeIn(function(){
        var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {center: {lat:latitude, lng:longitude}, zoom: 17});
      });

Comment: I have found the best answer for today, thank you so much!

Comment: Easy, simple and accurate! Also setting `height: 0px;` together with `visibility:hidden;` will prevent any div displaying its original placeholder.

Comment: do you mean set hidden firstly, then after loading, set the visibility not hidden?

Answer (score 0):

If you use JavaScript-based layout helpers (such as [Foundation Equalizer](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/equalizer.html)) you need to ensure that the map container has the definitive size before you load the map so you don't get the infamous grey map and certain attributes like `center` work as expected—or use the third-party plug-in's events to trigger a custom callback that *fixes* the map. E.g.:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(/*...*/);
$(document).on("after-height-change.fndtn.equalizer", function(){
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My map was hidden in a [Twitter Bootstrap tab](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tabs), and so wasn't visible when the map initialised, so I needed to call resize when the tab was selected like so:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {                 
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

#### How it should be fixed:

You must have to initialize the map after the container (where you place the map) get's visible,

Remember that loading and visibility is not same, you need visibility.

Like, I have many tabs & last tab contains the map,
I fixed this issue by:

```
$('#map-tab').click(function() {
    // init map
});
```

Here, I first making sure that the container gets visibility (as clicking that element reveals the section contains the map) then initialized the map

This worked fine for me;