# Google Map- API loading is very slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, angularjs

My page has been loaded with google map but using Jquery i am hiding it. On click of button it should display my google map loaded in that page. but i am not able to see the full map,i.e. am seeing only a part of map.
Below is my code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style id="my-css">
map,div[map] {
    display: block;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px
}
</style>
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/plunkr.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=true&amp;key=ABQIAAAAa24xicak8_ghHX58i7La7hRFh9iM79SNC94rOejOtdMRvQmJiBS6Uv5F_1BNSh9ZuSzFXyekHISgew">    </script>

<script
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
  center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
  zoom:7,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapProp);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#maps12").hide();
$("button").click(function(){
$("#maps12").show();
});
});
</script>
<script src="../dist/ng-map.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main">
        <header> 
        DEMO    
        </header>
        <section>
        <div id="maps12">
            <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <footer>
        <button>click me</button>   
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Their are directive available for Google Maps for AngularJS and UI Maps Look @
http://angular-google-maps.org/ and http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-map/

Answer (score 1):

You're loading the Google maps using window's `onload` event and for *a hidden element*.  Then you're again showing it *so the maps is bit stuck to get resized*.

So when you show the div, [trigger the `resize`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19003368/1671639) event of Google maps like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#maps12").hide();
    $("button").click(function() {
        $("#maps12").show();
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/75TXq/)

Comment: @NishanShah I don't understand what is not working, see here([fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/75TXq/1/)) I have reproduced your problem and the fix in my answer.  If still exists create a fiddle so that I can help you.

Comment: Its working perfectly but the loading time is very more... what should I do??

Comment: @NishanShah hmm, I don't find slowness in fiddle.  Not working in your project?  If possible share the url, let me try?