# google maps gray color not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ng-map

google maps gray color not working it only works if I resize the browser, I'm using AngularJS 1.6.4

[image]

html

```html
<ng-map zoom="8" center="{{h.latitude}},{{h.longitude}}" class="col s12 m12" scale-control="true" map-type-control="true" map-type-control-options='{position:"top_right", style:"dropdown_menu", mapTypeIds:["HYBRID","ROADMAP","SATELLITE","TERRAIN"]}' id="map"
  style="height:auto;">
  <marker position="{{h.latitude}},{{h.longitude}}" icon="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png">
  </marker>
</ng-map>
```

ini.js

```js
//home feed
var app = angular.module('homephotos', ['ngMap']);
app.controller('home', function($scope, $http, $timeout, NgMap) {
  $http.get("http://xxx")
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.home_feed = response.data.results;
    });

  //Init maps
  $scope.iniMap = function() {
    NgMap.getMap().then(function(map) {
      var center = map.getCenter();
      google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
      map.setCenter(center);
      console.log(map);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you mean that you see only grey area instead of the map until you resize your browser?

Comment: @Mosh Feu yes sir thats my problem

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19003291/863110) answer helps you..

Comment: you should try assigning  a valid width  and heigth .. eg:   style="500px; width; 500px; "

Comment: @Mosh Feu  thats the line of code im doing on the resize thanks

Comment: @scaisEdge still the same

Comment: Have your removed  the  style="height:auto;" ? ...

Comment: @scaisEdge yes sir

Comment: I'have missid  height  ... try   style="height: 500px; width; 500px; "

Comment: @scaisEdge yes i add the height but still gray

Comment: check if you have error in console .. and if you have not others style that override  the heigth and width for map ..

Comment: @scaisEdge search  for every detail nothing

Comment: tipically the grey map is related  at 2 factor .. 1) not valid fixed  width and heigth . 2) map is not visible when the page is load eg is in a hidden tab or a pop up   that is showed  in a second moment ..

Comment: @scaisEdge im using materialize so when i click the a see more icon is goes to text location + map in same div ,div class="card-reveal" http://materializecss.com/cards.html

Comment: then you should invoke the map creation  not when page is load  but when you click for accessing it .

Comment: @scaisEdge im doing that on the code above in a scope whit angular js

Comment: i'm not in angular.js  so i can't help for this  ...i can only suggest that if you create the map in a hidden div then you have the grey map ... for avoid this you shoudl create di map when you show the div

Comment: @scaisEdge thanks u so much for your time bless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just needed to call the one by one on clik , example in each off post when click the see more opition inigeocode

```
     $scope.init_geocode = function() {

         console.log('init_geocode');

        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
         latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(attrs.lat, attrs.lng);

           geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function  (results, status) {

             if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                 if (results[1]) {
                     var city = results[1].formatted_address;
                     element.text(city);
                 }
                 else {
                     element.text('Location not found');
                 }
             }
                else if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
                 setTimeout(function () {
                  $scope.init_geocode();
                  element.text('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
               }, 1000);

            }
               else {
                   element.text('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
               }

           });
        }
```